# After upgrading to c3p0 0.9.5.2, logging disappeared

Tags: logging, c3p0

After upgrading to 0.9.5.2, c3p0 logging disappeared from our logs. I followed instructions here [c3p0 logging](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_logging) but to no avail.

I added below file in classpath.

```
[c3p0.properties]
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=slf4j,log4j,jul,jdk14, java.util.logging,fallback
com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.suppressStackWalk=false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.

1. I'm not sure whether this is what you are indicating. The file should be called `c3p0.properties`, but there should be no `[c3p0.properties]` in the file. It should be a standard `java.util.Properties` file.
2. `com.mchange.v2.log.MLog` doesn't support a list. If you leave c3p0 to its defaults (don't set this property at all), c3p0 internally has an ordering of which logging library to try first. When you set `com.mchange.v2.log.MLog`, you choose one library to override that ordering. So your `c3p0.properties` file should include something like `com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=slf4j`, if [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org) is the logging library you are using.
3. If things get very confusing, you can always try `com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=fallback`, which will just print messages to standard error.
4. Leave off the `com.mchange.v2.log.jdk14logging.suppressStackWalk` stuff. It's not relevant unless you are using the `java.util.logging` library.

Comment: I can put the file anywhere in the classpath right?

Comment: yes, in the application's effective classpath. usually you can check you logs at INFO to verify that the configuration you expected came through, but if you're not seeing any logging, maybe not. as a failsafe, so you can see and debug stuff, you could set `-Dcom.mchange.v2.log.MLog=fallback` when you startup the JVM. (you can set properties in System properties as well as properties files.)